# field validation for string along with number in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a password field in one form. Now I have to validate in such a way that the field value should be a 7 digits string along with a number. Otherwise it will return false.

Please help me.

Comment: Please confirm if you mean, 7 characters long value which should contain at least one number digit?

Comment: Password validation rules need to be *absolutely explicit*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Create regex first

    Var regex =  /\w{7}\d/i;
    var yourvalue=$("#passwordid").value;


    regex.test(yourvalue){

    return true;

    }
else{
return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m sure there is a better way, but something like:

```
if ( /.{7}/.test(str) && /\d/.test(str) ) {
    //OK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript you can use the RegExp object.

```
var regEx = new RegExp(pattern, modifiers);
```

or more simply:

```
var pattern = /pattern/modifiers;
```

E.g.

```
var password = "abcdefg1";
var pattern = /\w{7}\d/i;

var isMatch = pattern.test(password);
```

Here are some expressions:

```
[abc]   Find any character between the brackets
[^abc]  Find any character not between the brackets
[0-9]   Find any digit from 0 to 9
[A-Z]   Find any character from uppercase A to uppercase Z
[a-z]   Find any character from lowercase a to lowercase z
[A-z]   Find any character from uppercase A to lowercase z
[adgk]  Find any character in the given set
[^adgk] Find any character outside the given set
(red|blue|green)    Find any of the alternatives specified
```

Metacharacters:

```
.   Find a single character, except newline or line terminator
\w  Find a word character
\W  Find a non-word character
\d  Find a digit
\D  Find a non-digit character
\s  Find a whitespace character
\S  Find a non-whitespace character
\b  Find a match at the beginning/end of a word
\B  Find a match not at the beginning/end of a word
\0  Find a NUL character
\n  Find a new line character
\f  Find a form feed character
\r  Find a carriage return character
\t  Find a tab character
\v  Find a vertical tab character
\xxx    Find the character specified by an octal number xxx
\xdd    Find the character specified by a hexadecimal number dd
\uxxxx  Find the Unicode character specified by a hexadecimal number xxxx
```

Quantifiers

```
n+  Matches any string that contains at least one n
n*  Matches any string that contains zero or more occurrences of n
n?  Matches any string that contains zero or one occurrences of n
n{X}    Matches any string that contains a sequence of X n's
n{X,Y}  Matches any string that contains a sequence of X to Y n's
n{X,}   Matches any string that contains a sequence of at least X n's
n$  Matches any string with n at the end of it
^n  Matches any string with n at the beginning of it
?=n Matches any string that is followed by a specific string n
?!n
```